# Unity3D UFO controls

Tags: unity

As a fairly new Unity programmer I'm working on a small game which involves an UFO *insert X-files theme*

Following YouTube-blogger Brackey's tutorial for 3rd person controls I've come this far, but when it comes to ascending and descending my UFO I can't wrap my head around how to do so.

```
    public CharacterController controller;
public Transform cam;

public float speed = 6f;
public float turnSmoothTime = 0.1f;
float turnSmoothVelocity;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

    if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
    {
        float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
        float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);

        Vector3 moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
        controller.Move(moveDir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("x"))
    {
        // Decend UFO
        transform.Translate(0, -1, 0);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
    {
        // Ascend UFO
    }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Kind regards

Comment: How does the Descend code you have now differ from what you want?

Comment: It moves instantly - I'm aimng to make it smooth like when moving around and turning my object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about this code here:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("x"))
{
    // Decend UFO
    transform.Translate(0, -1, 0);
}
```

- `Input.GetKeyDown` detects a key*tap*, not a key*hold*. It is only `true` during the first frame the player started pressing the key and is `false` while they keep holding it. What you probably want to do is lower the UFO while the player is holding the key and stop moving it when they release it. You would do that with [`Input.GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html). I would also recommend to not refer to keys by a string literal containing its name but use the constants in [`KeyCode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html) instead. So `if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X))`
- Remember that you do not know how long ago the last Update was. The time between updates can change depending on the framerate. So if you move objects by a distance, then you should always multiply that distance with `Time.deltaTime`. And while you are on it, you might want to also add another Inspector-exposed variable `public float descendSpeed` which allows you to adjust how fast you want the ufo to ascend and descend. So `transform.Translate(0, -descendSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try [lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html)ing the z-value from position A (start point) to position B (end point).

You can alternatively [lerp the whole 3D vector](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html). May be easier.

"Lerp" is an informal verb meaning to "linearly interpolate" a value. Non-linear interpolations look more organic and are also possible, but this should do what you want for now.